# Find all records that have a non-nil field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to define two variables as follows:

1. `@orders = Customer.find_all_by_order_date(nil)`
2. `@nonorders = Customer.find_all_by_order_date(!nil)`

The first works properly but the second doesn't. How can I find those customers whose order_date fields are not nil?

---

```
@nonorders = @customer.orders.find(:all, :conditions => "@customer.orders.order_date IS NOT NULL")
```

is giving me the following error:

`undefined method 'extract_options_from_args!' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class`

I've tried changing the conditions, such as `@orders.order_date`, `@customer.order.order_date`, etc. What's causing this error? Thank you!

Comment: In Rails, usually the class name for the model is first letters are upper case, singular. And the database table name is usually lowercase, plural. So it should be Customer.find(:all, :conditions => "customers.date IS NOT NULL") You should check into this issue. A plural model name instead of the usual singular (Customers instead of Customer) can lead to much confusion as you build out your sw.

Comment: The plural customers was unfortunately a typo - I do use Customer in my system. Thanks Larry!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rails3:

```
@nonorders = Customers.where("customers.date IS NOT NULL")
```

Rails2:

```
@nonorders = Customers.find(:all, :conditions => "customers.date IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: Hi Yannis, I've uploaded a follow-up question... still getting errors unfortunately.

Comment: or @nonorders = Customer.find(:all, :include => :orders, :conditions => ["orders.order_date IS NOT NULL AND customers.id = ?", @customer.id ])

Answer (score 1):

The string you pass as :conditions needs to be an sql fragment.

In the example given "customers.date" refers to the date field of the customers table. I think the "customers" bit is not strictly necessary, as the table name is clear from the context.

In your example the following should work:

```
@nonorders = @customer.orders.find(:all, :conditions => "order_date IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Rails 3.x

`@nonorders = Customers.where("date IS NOT NULL")`

```
Unless you are doing some non rails conventional stuff,
there should be no need to specify the table name within
the SQL payload of the the where method
```